# What settings control the maximum number of connections per user in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, timeout

We have some software that is throwing an exception "Pooled connection request timed out"

I know the reason for this and i know the fix. I just need to buy some time on the production server until i can release the software update.

Currently the software establishes about 640 simultaneous connections before it starts throwing this exception.

What database settings can i change which will increase the amount of simultaneous connections?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the SESSIONS parameter, which controls the maximum number of sessions for the system:

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM v$parameter
WHERE name = 'sessions';
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-52804B5A-164F-44F3-8980-F2593B58D807.htm#REFRN10197

You can also verify that there isn't a limit configured via user profile. Query the DBA_PROFILES view to check if a value is assigned for the SESSIONS_PER_USER parameter associated with your user:

```
select profile, resource_name, limit
from dba_profiles
where resource_name = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER';
```

Info regarding profiles:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01310

Comment: So the sessions value is set to 504 but im getting 640ish connections before it fails. 
Sessions_Per_User is set to UNLIMITED. Any further ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that many connections via v$session? Are you connecting via shared server or dedicated server? Also, you can try to increasing the value for the SESSIONS parameter.

Comment: The software takes up exactly 100 sessions every time, never changes. Its a dedicated server.

Comment: You can also check resource usage: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/V-RESOURCE_LIMIT.html#GUID-AC182B2E-8D26-43D7-A356-BE1F15BDF152

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check connection pool setting from application server?

Also, you can increase number of sessions per user by updating profile

Find profile for user:

```
SELECT profile FROM dba_users
WHERE username = '&user';
```

Alter profile

```
ALTER PROFILE  <profile_name>
SESSIONS_PER_USER <value>;
```

Can create new profile and assign to user:

```
ALTER PROFILE <profile_name> LIMIT
SESSIONS_PER_USER <value>;

ALTER USER PROFILE <profile_name>;
```